# Fire event when chrome extension starts

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

Is there a `chrome.runtime` event that fires when I click on the extension, and not `chrome.runtime.onStartup` as that fires every time a chrome profile with the installed extension would be started.

I am building an extension in React, and the closest idea I have that would work is firing the event in a `useEffect` in `App.tsx`, which is the root component that loads when the extension starts.

Any other ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The `action` popup runs each time you open it, so just put the code at the start of its script.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I apologize if this is a stupid question but could you please clarify on what you mean by the action popup? Thank you!

Comment: It's the popup declared via `action` in manifest.json that is shown when you click the extension icon in the toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapped the function in a `useEffect` which runs when the first popup mentioned in manifest.json loads up